# Iterate through folders which contains many text file and find Strings which match a specific mentioned String using Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset which contains 5 folders, each folder contains 100 .txt files. I have a text file which contains a set of stopwords. I want to iterate through each of the text files in each folder and remove the words that are in the stopwords.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write the Python code for this:

```py
import re
import os

for path, _, files in os.walk("datasetfolder"):
    for file_name in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)
        
        print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")
        
        with open("stopwords.txt", "r") as stopwords:
            for stopword in stopwords:
                with open(filepath, "r+") as f:
                    file_content = f.read()
                    new_file_content = re.sub(stopword, "", file_content)
                    f.seek(0)
                    f.write(new_file_content)
                    f.truncate()
```

Just make sure to replace `datasetfolder` with whatever path/directory your data set is located in.

Comment: Iam getting the following error .... 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 32: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Thank you, this helped solving my problem.